# What chapters does the fourth volume of Jason Shiga's Demon cover?

Tags: webcomics

I was recently introduced to Jason Shiga's *[Demon](http://www.shigabooks.com/index.php?page=001)*, a webcomic that he has since released in paper form, apparently in four volumes. My local library only has the first three (Amazon lists the fourth volume as to be released on November 17th, 2017). I found PDFs on his site for 20 chapters, but the 20th ends fairly abruptly with

> Jimmy and Hunter having a final showdown at the top of a Japanese castle, Hunter holding a katana to the neck of Sweet Pea.

Are there more than 20 chapters? Is there an actual end to the story or does it end with the standoff?

Comment: http://www.shigabooks.com/wordpress/comics/2014-03-22demon038.gif "Chapters 2 through 21..." It looks like there were 21 chapters originally.

Comment: The webcomic appears to be 720 panels long; http://www.shigabooks.com/index.php?page=720

Comment: You can view all of the original panels on wayback machine; https://web.archive.org/web/20160427082519/http://www.shigabooks.com/index.php?page=720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Valorum's answer above, it does continue past chapter 20. Although not all of the comic pages can actually be loaded via the Wayback Machine, the navigation panel clearly shows that the pages exist, and thumbnails can be viewed, which satisfies me that the story exists past that point. I will just calmly wait until November to finish reading it all.